# How to read an array of objects

Tags: c#, arrays, object

I have a C# list of objects and I'm trying to access its nested object.  Here's the structure from Visual Studio's debugger (sorry I can't embed images since I'm a newbie to the site):

```
>product.Product {Product.AxdEntity_Product_EcoResProduct[1]}
>>  - [0] {Product.EcoResProductMaster}         // #1 - Please note curley braces
>>>   - [Product.EcoResProductMaster]           // #2 - Please note brackes
>>>     + base {Product....
>>>     + ModelingPolicy
>>  + Identifier
```

**To access the properties in #1, I would do the following:**

```
var prod = product.Product[0];
```

Then I can access "Identifier" as such:

```
var identifier = prod.Identifier[0]...
```

**To access the properties in #2 (such as ModelingPolicy), I'm not sure how to go about it:**

```
var prod = product.Product[0][WhatShouldGoHere?].ModelingPolicy[0] ...?? I need help here
```

Eventually, I'd like to access the ModelingPolicy[0] like I did with prod.Identifier[0].
The Product class is being returned from a web service and I don't have access to its definition.  At least I don't think I do.

Thank you for any guidance!

Comment: You should switch from using an array to a [List<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx) or other generic collection. It's more appropriate in 99% of situations. Also, you should amend your post to include the class structure of your Product Class, and your Identifier class.

Comment: Looking in the debugger is not a great way to determine what code should be, since the debugger will show you more than you can determine at run time.  I would post the class definitions for the type that has the `Product` property and the type of the array (looks like `AxdEntity_Product_EcoResProduct`).

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I'll revise that but please note that I'm getting the results as a Product class from a web service so what's being listed here is all one object that the service returns back to me.  I'm just trying to access #2 and its properties.  I've updated the question in the hopes of making it more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to me like:

```
var ecoResProductMaster = product.Product[0].EcoResProductMaster; // Product type
var modelingPolicy = ecoResProductMaster.ModelingPolicy;
```

Have you tried this?

Comment: Perfect!! This gave me an idea. If I do product.Product[0].EcoResProductMaster, it gives me an error as "EcoResProductMaster" is not a property of Product[0].  But, if I cast as such: (EcoResProductMaster)product.Product[0] then I can access the inner object.  Thanks a million!!

Answer (score 0):

```
var productList = product.ToList()
foreach(var prod in productList)
{
    var identifier = prod.identifier
    foreach (var modelingPolicy in identifier.ModelingPolicy)
    {
     //do somthing with modeling policy
    }
    //do more stuff with product
}
```

As an aside please sort your naming conventions out. Having an array called `product` that contains a number of `Product` objects is just confusing

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to tell what you're going for here. Is this a List or array?

If it is a list then you can just foreach through the list to access each object.

Like if you have

```
List<SomeObject> someObjectList = new List<SomeObject>();
```

Then after you add a bunch of SomeObjects to the List you can just access the SomeObjects in a foreach loop.

```
foreach (SomeObject s in someObjectList)
{
   // then to access nested objects
   var n = s.SomeNestedObject;
   // do something with n
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your input.  The answer from SmartDev helped me access the objects in the inner array.  To do this, simply do the following:

```
var productMaster = (EcoResProductMaster)product.Product[0];
var modelingPolicy = productMaster.ModelingPolicy[0];
```

Of course, this is assuming that only one object is returned in the array, hence "[0]" but this should eventually go inside a foreach loop.

What I learned was if an object is returned without an index such as //#2 as noted above, a type cast should allow me to access it.  However, if an index is returned such as //#1, then using [0] will allow me to access its properties.